# In what ways should we evaluate system refactoring and why?

Tags: refactoring

This is a college assignment question but I haven't refactored any projects. I can just think of following points:

1. Has the refactoring improved cohesion and lowered coupling;
2. Has the refactoring improved code readability?
3. Is it more convenient to add more functions than before refactoring?
4. Performance improved?
   Do you have any ideas?like adding some points or correct my ideas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring can have one or more of the following goals (not an exhaustive list):

- reducing duplicate code (by extracting functions and types)
- enforcing invariants (by extracting types)
- improving development speed (extract functions, rename, lower cyclomatic complexity, lower compile times, lower number of responsibilities of a piece of code, lower dependencies, improve readability)
- optimize (for memory, execution time, cache friendliness, cpu usage)

If you have no clear ideas of what you are trying to achieve you could refactor with no clear benefit.